# How should this simple sql schema be modelled in Mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

I have been asked to create a simple Java application that will test MySQL and Mongodb from a performance point of view (college project). I am using a very simple sql schema:

3 tables: artist, album and track.

Relationships: one artist has many albums and one album has many tracks.

How would this be modeled in Mongodb?

Comment: What are your ideas? Have you tried anything? Why do you think would the schema be different? What do you think are the key criteria for schema design in SQL vs. NoSQL? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to have a single document containing all the information for a single artist.
Something like this:

```
class Track {
    int sequence;
    String title;
    ...
}

class Album {
    String name;
    List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Document
public class Artist {

    @Id
    private String name;
    private List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This isn't a bad approach since it's a test.  It also shows the fundamental difference between Entity/Relationship and Document models.  Note how relationships do not need to be maintained in a document model.  Note also that you don't need to 'ID' the albums and tracks.  They are just part of the document.

It looks much more natural from an object oriented perspective.

Comment: How would this look in a mongodb collection? Can I put all three tables in one collection or should I keep artist separate and nest the tracks in an album collection?

Comment: Mongo, being a document database, doesn't have any tables.  There's just one document called "Artist."